# systemd-networkd client-identifier DHCP Server and client DUID assignment with B.A.T.M.A.N mesh

Tags: linux, systemd, dhcp, systemctl, systemd-networkd

I have 3 Linux boxes running kernel 5.15 and systemd version 250.5+.

I have one of the boxes running as a B.A.T.M.A.N mesh master, with a DHCP Server managed by SystemD, and the other two are mesh clients.

I want the DHCP server to assign the mesh clients a single IP Address based on their Mac Address. I do not want them to be assigned an IP based on IAID/DUID. For this, the docs say to use **ClientIdentifier=mac**, which I have done. The problem is that I see multiple IP Addresses assigned to my clients, some based on the mac address, and some apparently based on the DUID.

How can I configure the DHCP server from systemd-networkd to honor the Client Identifier mac only with B.A.T.M.A.N? Thank you.

The bat0.network file on the master looks like this:

```
root@mesh-master:/etc/systemd/network# cat bat0.network
[Match]
Name=bat0

[Network]
Address=10.10.10.1/24
DHCPServer=true

[DHCPV4]
DUIDType=link-layer
ClientIdentifier=mac

[DHCPServer]
PoolOffset=10
PoolSize=8
EmitsDNS=yes
DNS=8.8.8.8
EmitNTP=yes
NTP=10.10.10.1
```

Networkctl mesh master status:

```
root@mesh-master:~# networkctl status bat0
● 6: bat0
                     Link File: n/a
                  Network File: /etc/systemd/network/bat0.network
                          Type: ether
                         State: routable (configured)
                  Online state: online
                        Driver: B.A.T.M.A.N. advanced
              Hardware Address: 66:4e:8d:94:88:b7
                           MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 1500)
                         QDisc: noqueue
  IPv6 Address Generation Mode: eui64
          Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 1/1
                       Address: 10.10.10.1
                                169.254.12.198
                                fe80::644e:8dff:fe94:88b7
                                fe80::d061:ecd7:c3fd:aef1
             Activation Policy: up
           Required For Online: yes
             DHCP6 Client DUID: DUID-EN/Vendor:0000ab113a78856d82eaf5680000
           Offered DHCP leases: 10.10.10.13 (to a6:d2:9c:dc:0c:61)
                                10.10.10.14 (to IAID:0x9cdc0c61/DUID)
                                10.10.10.17 (to IAID:0x127060c/DUID)
                                10.10.10.15 (to IAID:0x127060c/DUID)
                                10.10.10.12 (to 5a:e6:01:27:06:0c)
                                10.10.10.16 (to IAID:0x127060c/DUID)
```

Client networkd file ( bat0.network ):

```
root@mesh-client:~# cat /etc/systemd/network/bat0.network
[Match]
Name=bat0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4

[DHCP]
ClientIdentifier=mac
```

Networkctl status bat0 on mesh client:

```
root@mesh-client:~# networkctl status bat0 -l
● 6: bat0
                     Link File: n/a
                  Network File: /etc/systemd/network/bat0.network
                          Type: ether
                         State: routable (configured)
                  Online state: online
                        Driver: B.A.T.M.A.N. advanced
              Hardware Address: a6:d2:9c:dc:0c:61
                           MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 1500)
                         QDisc: noqueue
  IPv6 Address Generation Mode: eui64
          Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 1/1
                       Address: 10.10.10.13 (DHCP4 via 10.10.10.1)
                                10.10.10.14
                                fe80::1273:a607:f897:6bd3
                                fe80::a4d2:9cff:fedc:c61
                       Gateway: 10.10.10.1
                                10.10.10.1
                           DNS: 8.8.8.8
                           NTP: 10.10.10.1
             Activation Policy: up
           Required For Online: yes
                     Time Zone: UTC
               DHCP4 Client ID: a6:d2:9c:dc:0c:61
             DHCP6 Client DUID: DUID-EN/Vendor:0000ab11482afb1e3d85f23a0000

Mar 30 16:06:07 iot-gate-imx8plus systemd-networkd[459]: bat0: Link UP
Mar 30 16:06:07 iot-gate-imx8plus systemd-networkd[459]: bat0: Gained carrier
Mar 30 16:06:09 iot-gate-imx8plus systemd-networkd[459]: bat0: Gained IPv6LL
Mar 30 16:06:15 iot-gate-imx8plus systemd-networkd[459]: bat0: DHCPv6 lease lost
Mar 30 16:06:16 iot-gate-imx8plus systemd-networkd[726]: bat0: netdev ready
Mar 30 16:06:16 iot-gate-imx8plus systemd-networkd[726]: bat0: Link UP
Mar 30 16:06:16 iot-gate-imx8plus systemd-networkd[726]: bat0: Gained carrier
Mar 30 16:06:16 iot-gate-imx8plus systemd-networkd[726]: bat0: Gained IPv6LL
Mar 30 16:06:16 iot-gate-imx8plus systemd-networkd[726]: bat0: netdev exists, using existing without changing its parameters
Mar 30 16:06:47 iot-gate-imx8plus systemd-networkd[726]: bat0: DHCPv4 address 10.10.10.13/24, gateway 10.10.10.1 acquired from 10.10.10.1
```